# Why is Xcode 11.2.1 not appearing in the App Store updates tab?

Tags: macos, xcode, mac-appstore, upgrade, beta

I use OS X and have Xcode 11.2. I tried to push an app to TestFlight and got a warning that I needed to upgrade to Xcode 11.2.1.
Every time that I've upgraded Xcode in the past, I went to the Updates tab in the App Store, and downloaded the version there if there were any.

Right now there's no version 11.2.1 in the App Store.

**What I Want To Know:**

1) If 11.2.1 exists, why isn't it in the Updates tab of the App Store? Is it only new major and minor versions, and not patch versions, that show up there?

2) What's the best way to get version 11.2.1?

Comment: Here is how Apple's release cycle works: they make a new version, push it for manual download to their download portal, which goes through public testing and then if everything is alright they release new version to App Store.

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 11.2.1 GM seed is available at https://developer.apple.com/download/ after sign in.

I just started (and stopped) the download.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you know if there's any difference I should know about between downloading all my version of Xcode from the app store, and downloading this patch version from the website? Like, is there anything I should do other than just download this one you've linked and then continue downloading new versions from the app store in the future?

Comment: I just use it for necessity, not for power use .. so I don't know.  Please edit to specify it in your question and don't accept this answer.

Comment: It is not an answer.

Comment: @burtsevyg I'll quote myself again "don't accept this answer." Feel free to add answers to the question marked duplicate (the one I also voted for)