# How do I install Xcode if I'm getting this message "Xcode can’t be installed on “Mac HD” because macOS version 10.14.4"?

Tags: xcode, software-update

So I'm programming on a MacBook from mid-2010, and I have the most recent update (10.13.6) but when I try to install Xcode it says I need to update again, but it's not listed as an update in the AppStore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't update Xcode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232802/cant-update-xcode)

Comment: [Why is Xcode 11.2.1 not appearing in the App Store updates tab? \[duplicate\]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374515/why-is-xcode-11-2-1-not-appearing-in-the-app-store-updates-tab?noredirect=1&lq=1) Precedent is set and idk why another duplicate should be in HNQ.

Comment: Your Mac is too old to run the version of MacOS that XCode requires.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Recent versions of Xcode require macOS 10.14.4 or higher to run. Since you have 10.13.6, you can't run that version of Xcode. With 10.13.6 the most recent version of Xcode you can use is [Xcode 10.1](https://xcodereleases.com/).

Also, Macs made in 2010 cannot run macOS 10.14.4, which is why that version of macOS is not available to you as an update. Your Mac can't be updated past macOS 10.13.x.

You can do one of the following:

- Stick with Xcode 10.1. You can download it from https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.1/Xcode_10.1.xip (you'll need to log in to your Apple developer account).
- Upgrade to a newer Mac that will run macOS 10.14.4. You can find a list of the system requirements at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave

Comment: Will a virtual machine work as a sub-optimal workaround?

Comment: I don't know. You'd have to check and see what version of macOS can run on the virtual machine. If you can get at least 10.14, Xcode should work, slowly. It might only work for simulator builds and not for installing to devices.

Comment: For a virtual machine to work, it is important that the emulated hardware looks like a newer Mac so the MacOS installer will run.  Without having researched it, I would say it sounds very unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue lately too. I own an early 2011 MBP and was not able to update to Mojave either and therefore I could not install the latest Xcode.

While it isn't supported officially, there's  still a way to update to Mojave and run the latest Xcode. dosdude1 has created a patcher that allows you to install Mojave on your (officially) unsupported Mac, you can find it at http://dosdude1.com/mojave/ - they also have a [patcher for Catalina](http://dosdude1.com/catalina/)

**Please note**

- This is probably a violation of Apples ToS
- If you want to release your application in the App Store you might run into troubles (unlikely, albeit, still conceivable)
- You'll have to trust dosdude1, the patches are not open source, as far as I can tell
- The machine is not guaranteed to work as it did before

Answer (score 0):

checkout apple developer docs for macOS 10.14.6 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-mojave-10_14_6-release-notes

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to go to https://xcodereleases.com/ to see a list of downloads. If you go to https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/, you can see the supported versions.

For Mojave, I selected Xcode v11.3

I just installed it successfully.

Comment: The OPs machine cannot run Mojave OSX 10.14