# I can't download Xcode because my Mac mini is not up to date. However, there are no updates for my Mac mini. Is there anything to do?

Tags: xcode, mac-mini

My Mac mini is currently is version 10.12.6. Xcode requires "version 10.14.4 or laterV. However, when I check for available updates for my OS, there are none

Comment: When was your Mac Mini released (e.g. mid 2011, late 2012...) ?

Comment: You need to identify precisely which Mac Mini it is, but if it is indeed a 2008 or older, then I'm afraid you're stuck. Last supported OS on those is 10.12.6.

Comment: I used the serial code to find the model - https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i7-3.0-late-2014-specs.html

Comment: I have a mid-2010 iMac and the latest system I can install is 10.13.6.  May be the same for Mac mini.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Xcode if I'm getting this message "Xcode can’t be installed on “Mac HD” because macOS version 10.14.4"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379232/how-do-i-install-xcode-if-im-getting-this-message-xcode-can-t-be-installed-on)

Answer (score 3):

You can get earlier versions of Xcode from here:

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=xcode

This may be an option if you can't upgrade the OS.

Answer (score 1):

New major versions (like [macOS Catalina](https://apps.apple.com/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314)) need to be downloaded from the Mac App Store. They may not show up in System Preferences (nowadays they do, but AFAIR not in 10.12).

Depending on the model of Mac you have, you may not be able to upgrade to 10.14 though. Look for your model in https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/index-macmini.html and check the max OS version listed there.

---

Your model (https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i7-3.0-late-2014-specs.html) can be upgraded to run macOS Catalina. Just [download and install it from the Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314).

Answer (score -1):

If you can't upgrade to Catalina you can load an earlier version of XCode. The last system I could upgrade to is 10.13.6. The version of Xcode I'm running is 10.1. You should be able to find this version.